# Random Access File Write Ending Up With Extra Spaces Java

Tags: java, outputstream

I have the following code

```
    RandomAccessFile file_test = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Test Folder\\test4.doc", "rws");
    StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer();

    st.append("Writing to File");

    file_test.writeChars(st.toString());
    file_test.seek(0);

    System.out.println(file_test.readLine());
```

So the issues I have is that that file is being written, but there are spaces between each letter. This is the output:

W r i t i n g   t o   F i l e

instead of

Writing to File

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: No, there are no spaces in the output. Have you read the API documentation and understood what the writeChars method is actually supposed to do?

Comment: When you open the .doc file or .txt file spaces are  there. When I do writebyte there are no spaces, but I read that you do not want to represent characters with bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to write to a textfile use any of the Writer or OutputStream classes instead of RandomAccessFile which is meant for binary files.

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
        try
        {
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("textfile.txt"), "ISO-8859-1");
            osw.write("Here comes some output");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(osw != null) {
                try
                {
                    osw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a RandomAccessFile in this situation, try using writeUTF and see if that helps.

```
file_test.writeUTF(st.toString());
```

Don't forget to close your file when you're done.

```
file_test.close();
```